# Debug Assertion Fail, result_pointer != nullptr

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

I'm writing this program in C that grabs contact information. I'm passing the pointer of a `struct` within a `struct` to a function that gets the address information, but when scanning the information into the pointer location I get a debug error.

Here's my code:

```cpp
void getAddress(struct Address* address)
{
    // Street Number
    do  // Validate the street number
    {
        printf("Please enter the contact’s street number: ");
        scanf("%d", address->streetNumber); //<----where the error is
    } while (address->streetNumber <= 0);

    clearIS();    // Clears input stream
```

---

Comment: Pass a pointer to `streetNumber`, not the value of the variable: `scanf("%d", &address->streetNumber);`

Comment: There's no assertion in the code you've shown.

Comment: @jarmod it may be something inside the library implementation of scanf

Comment: @M.M Certainly looks that way and maybe it's as simple as `address->streetNumber` being zero. I'm surprised to see asserts active in a runtime library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short you should add `&(address->streetName)` and everything will work out.

The main reason for this behaviour is that `scanf` expect you to pass it a pointer to the place in memory where it should write an input.

In your current code you say to `scanf` to write 32 bits of user info into a memory that start with address from `address->streetName` and that's not what you want to do.

The same thing with `address->streetName` works fine because, I guess, you pass a pointer to array of chars to `scanf`. Because `address->streetName` is defined in your structure with type `char*` or `char[N]`.

Comment: The parentheses in `&(address->streetName)` are unnecessary and non-idiomatic.

Comment: I agree that they are redundant. I added them to explicitly show, that we want the address of the `streetName`.

Comment: The dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly — much more so than unary `&`.  There's no ambiguity if the parentheses are omitted.  As I said, they're unnecessary and non-idiomatic, but they aren't wrong.  But don't send code to me for review with parentheses like those in it.